# Does using Lazarus' Rags, the Ankh or Judas' Shadow change your baby for the sake of achievements?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Say I start a game as ??? and I pick up Judas' Shadow before meeting my unfortunate demise. I respawned as "dark" Judas now.

Will bosses I beat now count for ??? or for Judas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes — you do change into the respective baby. So if you start as ???, pick up Judas' Shadow, die and beat a boss, those bosses will be credited to Judas, not ???.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, while it does count as a Blue Baby victory if you die with The Ankh, and a Lazarus victory if you die with The Rags, Dark Judas is counted in the game's code as it's own individual charater and you will not recieve any Judas unlocks if you win with him.

Comment: That seems reasonable, actually; do you perhaps have some source? :)